# JS Menu and preloading screen scripts conflicting - Can you delay the preloading of a script?

Tags: javascript, delayed-execution

I have JS script for a menu on my website and JS scripts to run a preloading screen, the problem I am having is the menu script if interfering slightly with the loading screen script. I don't know JS very well and I am trying to find a solution where I can run the preloading script first and then execute the menu script once the loading script has completed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use document ready event. It will be fired, when document will be loaded with scripts. So you will need just to put scripts in right order in your js script's place.

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) is the link to the jquery ready event

Here is some more info about ready.

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Also Ill advise you to read about [async](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) and [defered](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) loading type. This will help you to make your loading page process faster.

A little bit more info about **delayed** script loading. As far as I know, if you not specify async or defer loading type, the second script will be loaded only when first script would come to your broswer.